# Why does the Azure SQL Server connector ask me for values of columns that have a default value when inserting a row?

Tags: sql-server, azure-logic-apps

When using the [SQL Server connector Insert row (V2) operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/#insert-row-(v2)), you have to fill in columns that have a default value in the database. Why? How can I circumvent this? See the screenshot below where I have to fill in an `Id` and a `CreatedAt` column that have default values of `newsequentialid()` and `getdate()` respectively.

I tried using the SQL `DEFAULT` keyword by simply filling in the field "DEFAULT" but it is treated as a string, in stead inserting "DEFAULT" into the database column.

[image: Logic App Designer]

Comment: have you tried just leaving the option blank?

Comment: @DougCoats It is not allowed, as denoted by the asterisk

Comment: Looks like while creating the table you have initialized the **"ID & createdAt"** columns as "Not Null" because of that those are  showing as mandatory in logic app while inserting a row . Could you change those column to  **"NULL"**  it will take default values & those will not  be showed up as mandatory in logic app

Comment: Could you please help us with more insights about the below  statement 
I tried using the SQL DEFAULT keyword but it is treated as a string.

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MT It is not possible to make the Id column NULL as it is the primary key.

Added to original question regarding DEFAULT keyword.

Comment: [Tiamo Idzenga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8611076/tiamo-idzenga): You cant avoid passing the values to Primary Key columns.
Best solution for you would be, creating/initializing variables with required default values and passing them to `Insert Row`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tiamo Idzenga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8611076/tiamo-idzenga): there is no direct way to make the `NOT NULL` Columns (with Default Values) optional or pass the default values, but I have found a alternative way to do the same.

**Steps to be followed:**

1. In the designer view, put any values for your columns. I have specified `nulll`
   [image]
2. Go to code view and locate the columns that you don't need.
   [image]
3. Just delete it from the JSON schema and Save it.
   [image]

**Note**: If you open the designer and try to edit, you have to do the above mentioned steps again.

Hope this helps your requirement.

Comment: Thanks Madhuraj, this is actually a fit solution for our requirements.